# Splitting a long script out int multiple files

Tags: python

Is there a way to split out sections of a script into a separate files and use something like an include statement to bring that code back into the main script where it is used when running it?  The split out sections aren't stand alone code or modules, just related sections of code where I do different operations.

My script is getting rather long and hard to read.  I tried using import but it looks like import will only work on a stand alone module or library.  I've tried searching on everything I can think of for this but all of the google returns are about importing and loading libraries.

Thanks

---

Thanks for the response but I see from your answer and re-reading my question,I left out one important detail.  I'm referring to a Python program/script here.

Comment: If your Python code is strait line, functions may used to organize the code in different sections making it shorter and easier. See `https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/` for more information.

Comment: Thanks bstip but that doesn't address the question.  I understand functions.  I just want to split those functions off to separate file so I don't have to scroll through all of those lines to get to the part of code I'm working on.  Like a #include statement I've used in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there is a way. It's a bit *off-topic* for RPi SE, but to save you the frustration of SO here's one way to do it:

Break your script into logically independent segments/files. Imagine a script file called `bigblob.sh`. Now, edit `bigblob.sh` by breaking it into 3 separate files that reflect a functional grouping: `smallblob1.sh`, `smallblob2.sh`, `smallblob3.sh`.

If `smallblob1.sh` is your "parent" script, and it is written in `bash`, you can insert `smallblob2.sh` and `smallblob3.sh` into it using the `source` command:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Begin smallblob1.sh
...
...
do this, do that do something else
...
...

source smallblob2.sh 

...
do more stuff
...

source smallblob3.sh 

...
finish up
...

exit 0
```

Those are the basics. For details, there's a good blog article posted in [Baeldung re use of the `source` command](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/source-include-files).